# Rails Constants using Initializers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, constants

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I am written a module in a file: config/initalizers/constants.rb

I have a defined a module with a constant and a static method. It's accessible when called in a view. The problem occurs when I want to call the method from in one of the environment files where I get an unitialized constant error. I believe the initializers are being run after the environment files are being loaded but I am not sure where best to place the method or file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may be solved by saving the constant as an environment variable instead. For development I can recommend the [Dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv). Of course it would need to be added to the production server environement as well, but Heroku etc make this very easy.

You add something like `CONSTANT_NAME=stringofcharacters1234` in a newly created `.env` file in the root rails directory and everytime you start up `rails s` it will parse that file and make those variables accessible to you through the `ENV` hash where you can access it like `ENV["CONSTANT_NAME"]` wherever it's needed.

I also prefer using `ENV.fetch("CONSTANT_NAME")` because this will raise an error if it's empty, helping in debugging if something fails because of an empty env variable.

Hope this is what you're looking for!